# Navigation bar on hover - CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this code, and it doesn't work. 
The sub-menu is not displaying when I hover over the main-menu.
The color changing seems to work but the second list is not showing under main menu on hover.
I can't find the problem...
Please help

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #navigationbar {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 30px;
    width: 90%;
    }
    #navigationbar ul {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    overflow: visible;
    }
    #navigationbar ul>li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    width: 130px;
    }
    
    #navigationbar li>a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    width: 115px;
    border-right: 1px black solid;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    color: #5d5636;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
    #navigationbar ul ul {
    margin-top: 2px;
    display: none;
    width: 160px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #dddddd;
    position: static;
    border: 1px #666666 solid;
    }
    
    #navigationbar ul ul li {
    position: relative;
    float: none;
    display: block;
    height: 28px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    }
    #navigationbar ul ul li>a {
    height: 100%;
    width: 96%;
    padding: 0 0 0 4%;
    line-height: 28px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    color: #000000;
    font-size 12px;
    font-style: normal;
    }
    #navigationbar li:hover > a {
    color: #220000;
    background-color: #eeeabe;
    }
    #navigationbar li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    }
    
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Nagłówek</h1>
    <nav id="navigationbar">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="/home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/AAAtest.html">A</a></li>
     <ul>
     <li><a href=/a.html>aaaaa</a></li>
     <li><a href=/b.html>bbbbb</a></li>
     <li><a href=/c.html>ccccc</a></li>
     </ul>
    <li><a href="/BBBtest.html">B</a></li>
     <ul>
     <li><a href=/aa.html>AAAA</a></li>
     <li><a href=/bb.html>BBBBB</a></li>
     <li><a href=/cc.html>CCCCC</a></li>
     </ul>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the closing tag for the `li` in the wrong place

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    #navigationbar {
      position: relative;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      height: 30px;
      width: 90%;
    }
    #navigationbar ul {
      position: absolute;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      list-style-type: none;
      background-color: #eeeeee;
      overflow: visible;
    }
    #navigationbar ul>li {
      display: block;
      float: left;
      height: auto;
      width: 130px;
    }
    #navigationbar li>a {
      display: block;
      height: 100%;
      padding: 0 0 0 10px;
      width: 115px;
      border-right: 1px black solid;
      font-size: 17px;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      background-color: #eeeeee;
      color: #5d5636;
      line-height: 30px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    #navigationbar ul ul {
      margin-top: 2px;
      display: none;
      width: 160px;
      height: auto;
      background-color: #dddddd;
      border: 1px #666666 solid;
    }
    #navigationbar ul ul li {
      position: relative;
      float: none;
      display: block;
      height: 28px;
      width: 100%;
      border: none;
    }
    #navigationbar ul ul li>a {
      height: 100%;
      width: 96%;
      padding: 0 0 0 4%;
      line-height: 28px;
      background-color: transparent;
      border: none;
      color: #000000;
      font-size 12px;
      font-style: normal;
    }
    #navigationbar li:hover > a {
      color: #220000;
      background-color: #eeeabe;
    }
    #navigationbar li:hover > ul {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Nagłówek</h1>
  <nav id="navigationbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/home.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/AAAtest.html">A</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href=/a.html>aaaaa</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=/b.html>bbbbb</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=/c.html>ccccc</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/BBBtest.html">B</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href=/aa.html>AAAA</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=/bb.html>BBBBB</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href=/cc.html>CCCCC</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Christ... Thank you so much @LGSon